# Installing Slic3r on Kubuntu 14.04 with NVIDIA

Tags: software, slic3r

I am running crazy trying to install Slic3r on my Kubuntu 14.04. It is a fresh Kubuntu and I downloaded the Slic3r package from them.

At first it worked well but then I changed the display driver to NVIDIA instead of the default Nouveau. I have repeated this operation a couple of times and I am almost sure that the NVIDIA driver screws up my system.

I have read and followed several "SOLVED" posts but none of them gave me a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this really a suitable question for this site? It's only marginally 3D printing related, and might be more suitable for a place where they deal with troubleshooting Ubuntu drivers.

Comment: I am having this problem only with this application, which is mostly used in the 3D Printing world. 
This is the reason why I ask here this question. 
There may be some other member having faced the same problem with this application.

Comment: Does the command line functionality of Slic3r work?

Comment: I have upgraded to Kubuntu 16.04 and it works after git cloning it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge problem with any linux distributions and Nvidia drivers. I have tried countless times to get that driver to work but it crashed my systems time after time. If your slicer works with the default driver i would not try to change it. If it doesn't then you may have to go to windows where the driver is guaranteed to work. I know this is not the answer you are looking for but unless you can code a new driver to work for Linux thats the only solution.

Comment: Yes John!  Unfortunately I got the same conclusion after so many trial and error tests.
Surprisingly Cura seems to work so far and I'm sticking to it.